# How is the symbol § called in German?

Tags: terminology

Often I see the symbol **§** on websites and also on official documents.
For example:

> Allgemeine Bestimmungen
>
> § 1 Zweck des Gesetzes; Anwendungsbereich
> § 2 Begriffsbestimmungen

I am interested to know how it is called and what is exactly purpose of this symbol?

Comment: Wie heißt es denn in Deiner Sprache und welche ist das? Ist diese Bezeichnung nicht im Wörterbuch vermerkt?

Comment: "paragraph" is the name. It means a chapter in a law, contract or agreement. Your question is not really about the German language.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I wouldn't have known that this is called "Paragraphenzeichen", maybe guessed it. If you never really came in contact with it, you might not know the name on your native language.

Comment: @peterh have you seen many other languages using it so that you can be sure that the OP should have associated a meaning with § because she or he speaks probably one of those languages? If the answer is no (as I presume) then the question is on topic here.

Comment: @c.p. I've checked [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/§). It was originally a Greek character, after various translations. Legal usage roots probably in the Holy Roman Empire / Habsburg Empire. The law of their successor states roots in the *Bürgerliches Gesetzuch* today. This is why most Middle European country law uses it. However, it is used in the U.S. law, too. Thus, although it is now a world-wide used symbol, it has really German roots.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

§ is the [Paragraphenzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraphenzeichen) - [section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) in English.

> § is often used when referring to a specific section of [legal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_code).

It's used to refer to *Paragraphen* in German, e. g. *§ 1 des StGB* ([Strafgesetzbuch](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/)). If you refer to several sections, its plural is §§.

---

Note that *Paragraphenzeichen* (or *Paragrafenzeichen*) is the name of the symbol. When you use it to denote a section, you say *Paragraph*. E. g. in the above example, you would say *Paragraph 1 des StGB*.

Comment: its called  Paragraphenzeichen ?

Comment: Yes, "Paragraphenzeichen" or "Paragrafenzeichen".

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraphenzeichen

Answer (score 4):

The symbol is called »Paragraphenzeichen« (*paragraph sign*) but when you read it, you don't say »Paragraphenzeichen«. You just say »Paragraph«:

> **§ 1.** Geltungsbereich.
> **§ 2.** Begriffsbestimmungen.

will be read as

> **Paragraph eins.** Geltungsbereich.
> **Paragraph zwei.** Begriffsbestimmungen.

---

But paragraphs are often subdivided into smaller parts. (All examples taken from Austrian StVO (Straßenverkehrsordnung).)

> **§ 4.** Verkehrsunfälle.
> **(1)** Alle Personen, deren Verhalten am Unfallsort mit einem Verkehrsunfall in ursächlichem Zusammenhange steht, haben
> **a)** wenn sie ein Fahrzeug lenken, sofort anzuhalten,
> **b)** wenn als Folge des Verkehrsunfalles Schäden für Personen oder Sachen zu befürchten sind, die zur Vermeidung solcher Schäden notwendigen Maßnahmen zu treffen,
> **c)** an der Feststellung des Sachverhaltes mitzuwirken.
> **(2)** Sind bei einem Verkehrsunfall Personen verletzt worden, ...
> **(3)** Auch der Zeuge eines Verkehrsunfalles ...
> **(4)** Jedermann ...
> ...

When you want to refer to a specific part of a paragraph, you do it this way:

- written:

> Laut **§ 4 StVO 1960, Abs 1, Lit c** muss jeder, dessen Verhalten in einem ursächlichen Zusammenhang mit einem Verkehrsunfall steht, an der Feststellung des Sachverhalts mitwirken.

- spoken:

> Laut **Paragraph vier der Straßenverkehrsordnung von 1960, Absatz**<sup>1</sup> **eins, Buchstabe**<sup>2</sup> **c** muss jeder, dessen Verhalten in einem ursächlichen Zusammenhang mit einem Verkehrsunfall steht, an der Feststellung des Sachverhalts mitwirken.

<sup>1</sup> Note, that both words, *»Paragraph«* and *»Absatz«* mean *"paragraph"* in English, but in German the word *»Paragraph«* is not a synonym for *»Absatz«.* The word *»Paragraph«* is only used for sections in laws and similar normative documents.
<sup>2</sup> The abbreviation "lit" stands for latin "litera" which means *"letter"*. In spoken German you can say *»Litera«* or *»Buchstabe«.*

---

Sometimes you want to refer to more than one paragraph. Then you use the symbol **§§:**

- written:

> In den **§§ 48 - 54** werden die Straßenverkehrszeichen geregelt.

- spoken:

> In den **Paragraphen achtundvierzig bis vierundfünfzig** werden die Straßenverkehrszeichen geregelt.

Comment: "Paragraf" darf und soll man übrigens seit neuestem mit einem "f" schreiben, was vor allem in englischen Texten sinnvoll ist, weil dort Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem "Absatz" (*paragraph*) besteht.